# Sendgrid using PHP does not send email

Tags: php

Below is the code sending email using Sendgrid in PHP. I have been to the Sendgrid documentation. But I can not find out the solution. Thanks in advance.

```
<? php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
require 'sendgrid-php/lib/SendGrid.php';
require 'sendgrid-php/lib/SendGrid/Email.php';
require 'sendgrid-php/lib/SendGrid/Response.php';
$sendgrid = new SendGrid('8ZArX0z3S6qOi1-xxxxx');

$email = new SendGrid\Email();
$email
    ->addTo("xxx@yahoo.com")
    ->setFrom("xxx@yahoo.com")
    ->setSubject("Subject goes here")
    ->setText("Hello World!")
    ->setHtml("<strong>Hello World!</strong>");

    $sendgrid->send($email);
?>
```

Comment: Have you changed the `xxxxx` to something else? It looks like it is an identifier of some kind, which needs to be changed.

Comment: yes I have inserted my email id both the places

Comment: it even does not show in the Sendgrid that I message is gone through